# _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'tostring'

Tags: python

The code below generates this error. I can't figure out why. If ElementTree has parse, why doesn't it have tostring? http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

...

tree = ElementTree()
node = ElementTree()

node = tree.parse(open("my_xml.xml"))
text = node.tostring()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tostring` is a method of the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module, not the confusingly similarly-named `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` class.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring

tree = ElementTree()
node = tree.parse(open("my_xml.xml"))
text = tostring(node)
```

Answer (score 3):

tostring() is actually a function of the ElementTree module not a method of the ElementTree wrapper class.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> x = ET.fromstring('<xml><one>one</one></xml>')
>>> x     
<Element xml at 7f749572f710>
>>> ET.tostring(x)
'<xml><one>one</one></xml>'
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working. I keep getting `'str' object has no attribute 'iter'`

Answer (score -1):

The docs you've linked to do not support the existence of a `ElementTree.tostring()` method.

Also, your call to `tree.parse()` rebinds `node`.